# The OLE DB provider “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” for linked server “(null)”

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, server

I'm trying to run a store procedure which has a Openrowset, in the server machine I can execute it, but when I try in other machine, I get the following error message:

> SQL Server: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” for linked server “(null)”

I looked for answers over the internet but no one helped me. I also installed  the AccessDatabaseEngine for 32 bits

**Server:** SQL Server 2008, Express Windows 7 32 bits.

**The other machine:** Windows 7 32 bits

The store procedure:

```
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Estadisticas_tmp(Estadisticas.Nombre_Granja, Fecha_Ingreso, Fecha_Egreso, Mortandad, Faltante, Promedio_Kilos, Conversion, Ganancia,Porcentaje_Mortandad)
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
                    ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @nombre_archivo + ';HDR=YES;IMEX=1'',
                    ''SELECT GRANJA,FECHA_ING, FECHA_EGRE, MORTANDAD, FALTANTE, GANANCIA, CONVERSION, PROMEDIOKILOS,PORCENTAJE_MORTANDAD FROM [ESTADISTICA$]'')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Please, provide more details: server version, windows version, etc.

Comment: Server:
SQL Server 2008 Express
Windows 7 32 bits

The other machine:
Windows 7 32 bits

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8558bed9-7dea-4a66-9f16-8ac4c07dd2fb/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microsoftaceoledb120-for-linked?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: No luck with those, I have been trying with a connection tester sending the query of the store procedure, but the message still apears. In the server machine, I can execute the store procedure perfectly, the problem is from other machine :\